# Where is the bookmarks toolbar icon located?

Tags: 10.04, icons, firefox

Where is the bookmarks icon file located for Firefox 9.0a1 in Ubuntu 10.04? I want to change it to the default Humanity bookmarks icon. Doing `locate bookmarks` and `locate bookmarks.png` has turned up no useful results.

Here is the icon that I'm looking for to change. I just need to know the path to it:

[image: Firefox Bookmarks Icon]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to help from @Jo-Erlend Schinstad, I've learned that Firefox uses a sprite for some of its toolbar icons, including the icon it uses for the Bookmarks menu. The image can be found by navigating to `/usr/lib/firefox-*/` (* representing the version) and opening `omni.jar` with Archive Manager (File Roller). Then, in Archive Manager, navigate to `/chrome/browser/skin/classic/browser/`. The sprite Firefox uses for its toolbar items is named `Toolbar.png`.

The reason I wanted to know this was to make the icon consistent with the Humanity icon theme. I edited changed the Bookmarks icon in the sprite to use Humanity's default Bookmarks icon. If you'd like to do the same, replace the default `Toolbar.png` with mine here:

[image: new toolbar.png]

This is how my toolbar looks with the replaced `Toolbar.png`:

[image: new firefox toolbar]

Comment: Hi, do you have the small version of this sprite by any chance?

Comment: No, sorry, but it's very easy to open the sprite in GIMP, find a suitable icon in `/usr/share/icons/`, and copy and paste.

Answer (score 3):

You should always say which version of an application you're using when you ask for help. Is there any good reason why you were looking for bookmarks.png, or was it just a guess? :)

In order to find out which files that is installed with a package, use `dpkg -L`. I did `dpkg -L firefox | less`, and it showed me lots of files, including `/usr/lib/firefox-6.0/chrome/icons/default`

But that wasn't it, so I moved upwards. I eventually found `file:///usr/lib/firefox-6.0/omni.jar` which seems to provide the default skin. Skinning Firefox is popular, so you'll probably not have any difficulties finding information about that.

Comment: It was just a guess. I found the icon in `/chrome/browser/skin/classic/browser/Toolbar.png`. Apparently Firefox uses a sprite for some of it's toolbar icons. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Thomas Boxley: Great you posted you edit! You may want to consider to edit in the link (http://i.imgur.com/BAYzU.png) to your own question to make sure it is not deleted over time.

Comment: @Takkat: K, done :)